# How to block all subdomain in a site from search engine?

Tags: indexing, web-crawler, robots.txt

I have around 300+ subdomains for my site, I need to block them from indexing in search engines. 
I saw this robots.txt code
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

But I need to do it for every subdomain, is there an easier way to do it with single robot.txt file in the root of the main domain.

Comment: I believe you can use regex for your purpose here. And you can actually use the same robots.txt for all sub-domains. :P

Comment: By the way - what happens when you use your robots.txt with Disallow:/ in the root. How can you say the robot is exploring your sub-domains?